# Accessing session variable from WCF service by parsing sessionID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, session

Is it possible to access a Asp.net session variable from a WCF service by using the SessionID.

My service is called from jQuery and my thought was to parse the sessionID using jQuery to the service and then set the needed variables, but I can not find a way to do this.

Here is my jQuery call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: baseURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
```

Does anyone know if it is at all possible or suggest another way set a session related variable?

Comment: I've already used a AJAX-Enabled WCF-Service in my application to access data on the server using jquery. But there i didn't need to pass the session id or something like that, as the session cookie will be automatically passed to the server (also when using jquery). If you're using the URL-Session then this is something else ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery request from the browser will already include the session cookie, so if you're running your WCF service in ASP.NET compatibility mode it already has direct access to the current `HttpContext` which means you can access the Session State from there. Here's how you can enable this integration on your WCF service:

First, add the following attribute to your service class:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Next, add the following to your service .config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/> 
    <!-- whatever else you already have -->
</system.serviceModel>`
```

Once you do this you can access the current `HttpContext` to grab the Session State like so:

```
public void MyServiceOperation()
{
    string myStoredValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStoredValue"];

    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I added the code you wrote above, but it seams that I can not access my variable. My session variable has been set in the aspx document also containing the jquery code. But when I am trying to acces the variable from my web-service (hosted in a virtual directory on the same IIS) it returns 0 on the count on HttpContext.Current.Session.count? Any other ideas?

Comment: Okay now I think I found the problem. It is not possible to host the WCF service in a virtual directory and the website in another! They have to be in the same application to handle the same session (it make sense). When I moved my service to the application it worked fine, so I think the problem is solved :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could store the session object in the database itself to allow you access in different web apps or platforms.